# angularjs run named function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is wrong with this?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .run('pageTitle', pageTitle);

    function pageTitle($rootScope, $http) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
            $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        });
    }

})();
```

I´m getting this error

**Error: ng:areq**

**Bad Argument**

*Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Moncef Hassein-bey's answer, `.run()` only accepts one argument.

You also need to inject `$rootScope` and `$http` into your function or you will face further issues. Place the following line above your `pageTitle` function:

```
pageTitle.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http'];
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. should I do this for every function?

Comment: Only where the function requires dependency injection. If you are not passing any dependencies to the function then there is no need to `$inject` anything. Just to clarify, this only applies to named functions you use in your Controller, Service, Factory etc.

Answer (score 1):

.run() accepts one argument, and it must be a function, so remove the first string.

```
angular.module('app').run(pageTitle);
```